# D2D1 Path Geometry: Behavior of intersecting figures

Tags: c++, direct2d

I have the following code (+ some error handling) that generates 2 rectangles using a single ID2D1PathGeometry instance:

```
  m_geometry->Open(&m_geometrySink);

  m_geometrySink->BeginFigure(D2D1::Point2F(100, 100), D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN_FILLED);

  m_geometrySink->AddLine(D2D1::Point2F(300, 100));
  m_geometrySink->AddLine(D2D1::Point2F(300, 300));
  m_geometrySink->AddLine(D2D1::Point2F(100, 300));

  m_geometrySink->EndFigure(D2D1_FIGURE_END_CLOSED);

  m_geometrySink->BeginFigure(D2D1::Point2F(200, 200), D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN_FILLED);

  m_geometrySink->AddLine(D2D1::Point2F(400, 200));
  m_geometrySink->AddLine(D2D1::Point2F(400, 400));
  m_geometrySink->AddLine(D2D1::Point2F(200, 400));

  m_geometrySink->EndFigure(D2D1_FIGURE_END_CLOSED);

  m_geometrySink->Close();
```

This generates the following rectangles: [image]

As you can see the are where they intersect is left without any filling.

I am wondering: **Is it possible to change this behavior (I want the intersecting area to be filled as well) without having to create an additional ID2D1PathGeometry object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should invoke `m_geometrySink->SetFillMode(D2D1_FILL_MODE_WINDING);` prior to adding figures. Otherwise default fill mode which is alternate will be used instead.